# Setting text properties in Emacs when using font-lock-defaults

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to set some background text properties in my Emacs buffer. For instance,

```
(set-text-properties pos1 pos2 '(face '(:background "cyan")))
```

But I cannot get it to work. I think I have a clue why it does not work:
I am also using a major mode that uses `(setq font-lock-defaults '((some-font-lock-keywords)))`
If I comment out that assignment to `font-lock-defaults` it works fine.

Comment: A side comment: Text properties are considered part of the text, so Emacs behaves the same when changing them as when changing text, for example, it's not possible to set text properties when the buffer is read-only, and buffers are marked as "modified" when text properties are changed. If you would like to make the changes invisible (like font-lock do) you can wrap your code with the macro `with-silent-modifications`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a bit of code that you can paste into `*scratch*`:

```
(let ((inhibit-modification-hooks t))
  (make-face 'temp-face)
  (set-face-background 'temp-face "cyan")
  (put-text-property 1 50 'face 'temp-face))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! What is the purpose of `inhibit-modification-hooks`?

Comment: Just `f1 v`, that's as much as I can say besides that it doesn't work without.

Comment: I think there is no need to call `make-face` here, you can simply do `(put-text-property pos1 pos2 'face '(:background "cyan"))` provided you set `(inhibit-modification-hooks t)` first...

Comment: @abo-abo kudos for the `inhibit-modification-hooks`! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wrt your code: Drop the second quote mark. And be aware that `set-text-properties` ***replaces*** all existing text properties.  You might want to only specify the `face` property, without erasing other properties.  See `(elisp) Changing Properties`.

And yes, it is likely that font lock interferes here -- that is typically the case when you apply a `face` property.  Look at the code in various highlighting libraries to see how you can work around this.  But generally, if you want font locking then you should do your highlighting via font-lock also.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on my code. Regarding `set-text-properties` and `put-text-property`: I think the syntax is a little bit different for these two functions. So both the quote marks should actually be there..

Comment: No, the second quote mark is *not* needed.  Did you try it?  And yes, `set-text-properties` and `put-text-property` are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following to also work: Replace `'font` with `'font-lock-face` :

```
(set-text-properties pos1 pos2 '(font-lock-face '(:background "cyan")))
```

or maybe better: (as suggested by @Drew and @abo-abo)

```
(put-text-property pos1 pos2 'font-lock-face '(:background "cyan"))
```

then there seems to be no need to set `(inhibit-modification-hooks t)` first..

See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Precalculated-Fontification.html